# OkHttp proxy settings

Tags: java, json, post, proxy, okhttp

I have to setup a proxy to send a JSON using POST, using proxyHost and proxyPort.

```
public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
  Proxy proxyTest = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,new InetSocketAddress("proxy", proxyPort));

  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient()
  .proxy(proxyTest)
  .build();
  //OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
  //builder.proxy(proxySAP);
  //client.setProxy(proxySAP)
  //OkHttpClient client = builder.build();;

  String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {

    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(body)
        .build();
    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
      return response.body().string();
    }
  }
```

When i try to use the proxyTest that I've saw on some answers here it points an error:

> The method proxy() in the type OkHttpClient is not applicable for the
>   arguments (Proxy)

Iam using the OKHTTP 3.3.1(okhttp3)

My question is, what should I do? I did some tests like this:

> OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
>   builder.proxy(proxyTest);
>   client.setProxy(proxyTest)
>   OkHttpClient
>   client = builder.build();

But nothing works so far.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You were calling [OkHttpClient.proxy()](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.html#proxy--)

But you want to call [OkHttpClient.Builder.proxy(Proxy)](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html#proxy-java.net.Proxy-).

Comment: You can set the proxy that the JVM uses, with the flags (e.g.) `java -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.100 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8800 myclass`  (Useful for when okHttp change their api AGAIN).

Comment: The -D JVM properties are NOT respected by OkHttp3, so the above doesn't work.  You need to programmatically set it instead.

Comment: Does nobody include the imports around here? You're using magic if you don't. So frustrating. Not a single answer shows an import statement.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().proxy(proxyTest).build();
```

If we use the builder to input the proxy, it will work like a charm =D

Comment: For mocking unit test reasons, I need to pass the OkHttpClient() class from the constructor args. So I am not able to add a proxy for the OkHttpClient() with the builder. Is there any other way to use the object of OkHttpClient() instead of new OkHttpClient.Builder() ?

Comment: okHttpClient.newBuilder().proxy(proxy).build(); worked for the objects ( without new OkHttpClient() )

Answer (score 11):

okhttp version:`3.11.0`. SOCKS proxy example

```
String hostname = "localhost"/*127.0.0.1*/;
int port = 1080;
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS,
        new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port));

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .proxy(proxy)
        .build();
```

Comment: Thank you for your example, how can I use auth for socks5 in the example above? please add code sample if you can

Comment: visit this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554380/okhttpclient-proxy-authentication-how-to @vasilevich

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but the example provided in the link works only with HTTP proxy, not socks5, I already tried.

Answer (score 9):

SOCKS5 Auth example

I think it's the easiest working soulution. But it seems to me that it can be not 100% safe. I took this code from this code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16340273/9466638) and modified it because my proxy's RequestorType is SERVER. 
Actually, java has a strange api for proxies, you should to set auth for proxy through system env ( you can see it from the same link)

```
final int proxyPort = 1080; //your proxy port
final String proxyHost = "your proxy host";
final String username = "proxy username";
final String password = "proxy password";

InetSocketAddress proxyAddr = new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, proxyAddr);

Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
  @Override
  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    if (getRequestingHost().equalsIgnoreCase(proxyHost)) {
      if (proxyPort == getRequestingPort()) {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
});


OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .proxy(proxy)
        .build();
```