# okhttp3.OkHttpClient.setProxy cannot find symbol

Tags: spring-boot, okhttp

I updated my okhttp to okhttp3 because of vulnerability issue, but the class OkHttpClient doesn't have setProxy now.  What should I do?  Should I rewrite the code with new one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in okhttp3, it's using [proxy()](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html#proxy-java.net.Proxy-) for the [OkHttpClient.Builder](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html). [proxy()](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html#proxy-java.net.Proxy-) has the same documentation as [setProxy() in older okhttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.html#setProxy-java.net.Proxy-).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866902/okhttp-proxy-settings) are some examples using proxy().

Comment: Thanks @Haoliang I put this,
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.server.com", 8080));
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
      .proxy(proxy)
      .build();