# Spring Boot Recaptcha Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, okhttp

I'm developing an application on spring boot, however I needed to integrate recaptcha for security purposes on various forms, however the connection always results in a connection timed out, I verified api and the url with postman and it goes through and returns an answer, however on Java code times run out and I get the error `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect` I don't know what I'm doing wrong I use the postman code that provides on "Java OK HTTP". code is the next one.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
.url("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=XX&response=XXX")
.get()
.addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
.addHeader("postman-token", "f47548e1-a9e0-9065-7f76-dced294bddcb")
.build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

However I don't seem to get where the error is, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `Connection timed out` error, so we can say that:

- since this is not an `Unknown host` error, you must have a DNS that gives an IPv4 or IPv6 address for www.google.com
- since this is not a `destination unreachable` error, you have a route to a gateway and this gateway is a local router that has a default route.

Therefore, the timeout for `connect` means you have sent a TCP SYN packet to a destination, and this packet has been dropped somewhere in your local network or at the interface between your network and the Internet, **in a firewall** (since you have not received any ICMP/ICMPv6 packet saying something was wrong - a standard router should have sent you such an information).

The problem is with the first packet (TCP SYN), so your problem can not be relative to your `addHeader()` calls in your source code. Those headers are never sent, in your case, with this error.

Since www.google.fr has IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, there are two possibilities:

- either you have a local IPv6 router that sends RA advertisments, but is not connected to the Internet with IPv6.
  Try this to check this case:

replace:

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=XX&response=XXX
```

by:

```
https://[2a00:1450:400c:c04::6a]/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=XX&response=XXX
```

If you continue to get a `timeout`, this means you have an IPv6 router that is badly configured.

- or you have a firewall and need to use a proxy

replace:

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=XX&response=XXX
```

by:

```
https://74.125.206.104/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=XX&response=XXX
```

If you continue to get a timeout, this means you have a firewall and should use a proxy.

Comment: Actually I got a timeout with last conf, but I got an unreachable with the first one, how is it possible to use a proxy ??

Comment: Since you have a timeout with last conf and unreachable with first one, you are right: you need to use a proxy. You certainly have to use a proxy with authentication (the most common case). So, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554380/okhttpclient-proxy-authentication-how-to

Comment: At the very end it did not work, but worked on my other machine, proxy was a being a pain in the ass, problem is a configuration  was needed since I work inside  a Virtual machine, thank you so much.