# java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to overpass-api.de/178.63.48.217:80

Tags: java, okhttp, overpass-api

Friends !!! I am new to Java & I have written my first following coding to get data thru Overpass API.

## Problem Statement

But Overpass API server is not responding to Java_Servler_request (Hence Connection Timeout happens).

### My Trials

1. I tried thru Chrome Manually & I am receiving data. It means *Overpass Server* is working fine.
2. I tried to call localhost (instead of Overpass API), it is responding thru OkHttp3. It means *OkHttp3* is working fine.

**Main code calling class**

```
URL="http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter";
value ="?data=way(around:100,22.36432,73.19266)[power~\"\"];(._;>;);out;";
HttpCaller API =new HttpCaller();
response.getWriter().println(API.APIGet(URL+value));
```

**Class Calling Overpass API**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class HttpCaller
{
    OkHttpClient client;
    String rspns;

    public HttpCaller()
    {
        try
        {
            client = new OkHttpClient();
            OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            builder.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
            builder.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
            builder.writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
            client = builder.build();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();System.out.println(e);}
    }

    public String APIGet(String url) throws IOException
    {       
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
        System.out.println(request.url());

        try 
        { 
            Response response = null;
            System.out.println("new Call...");
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            System.out.println(response.code());
            rspns =  response.body().string(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();System.out.println("Exception is "+e);} 

        return rspns;
    }
}
```

**Result thrown**

```
http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=way(around:100,22.36432,73.19266)[power~%22%22];(._;%3E;);out;
new Call...
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to overpass-api.de/178.63.48.217:80
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:247)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:165)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)Exception is java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to overpass-api.de/178.63.48.217:80
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
```

**Testing URL on Chrome**
[My Desktop Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YOK0.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by setting the proxy setting for the request through OkHttp.

Source : [OkHTTPClient Proxy authentication how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554380/okhttpclient-proxy-authentication-how-to)

Comment: This looks like a mobile app. Please be aware that there's a usage policy for Overpass API you need to adhere to, limiting the maximum number of requests per day. You could experience similar error message in case you get blocked by exceeding your quota.

Comment: i am learning + developing a concept (not full fledge app)... whenever the full-fledge app will be rolled out, it will be definitely with commercial licences for APIs

Comment: This is open source, there are no commercial licenses. However, if you exceed limits, you need to switch to your own infrastructure.